# Confusion regarding Heine-Borel

Tags: real-analysis

In my calculus book, the Heine-Borel theorem is stated as:

> If a set of intervals $S$ satisfies the following properties: 
>  1. There exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a <b$ such that for all $I \in S$, $I \in [a,b]$, and there exists intervals (possibly same) $I_1, I_2 \in S$ such that $a \in I_1$ and $b \in I_2$. 
>   2. For every $x \in [a,b]$, there exists an $I \in S$ such that $x \in I$. 
>  Then it's possible to choose finitely many intervals $I_1, I_2, I_3, \cdots I_n$ (all member of $S$ ) such tat $I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3 \cdots \cup I_n = [a,b]$

**Updae: New pseudo counterxample** Okay, how does Henie Borel works when I divide $[-1,1]$ in the intervals $[1,.5), [.5, .25), [.25, .125), \cdots, [0, -.6), (-.5, -1]$ ?
Where did I mess up ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the statement excludes degenerate intervals, i.e., sets of the form $[x,x] =\{ x\}$.

Comment: When you write $I\in [a,b]$ in 1. you mean $I\subset [a,b].$...... The Heine-Borel theorem only applies when every member of $S$ has non-zero length. E.g. it does not apply if $a<b$ and $S=\{[x,x]: a\leq x\leq b\}.$

Comment: What does $I\in[a,b]$ mean? Is that a typo for $I\subseteq[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0):

This statement of the Heine-Borel theorem is wrong.  To get a correct statement, you need to additionally require that every element of $S$ is either an *open* interval, a half-open interval of the form $[a,c)$ or $(c,b]$, or the entire interval $[a,b]$.

(Note that contrary to what some have commented, it is not enough to just exclude degenerate intervals.  For instance, a counterexample with nondegenerate closed intervals is $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and $S=\{[-1,0],[1/2,1],[1/3,1],[1/4,1],\dots\}$.)

Comment: Okay, how does Henie Borel works when I divide $[-1,1]$ in the intervals $[1,.5), [.5, .25), [.25, .125), \cdots, [0, -.6), (-.5, -1]$ ?

Comment: Those intervals don't meet the hypotheses...for instance, $[.5,.25)$ is not any of the allowed kinds of interval.

Comment: Why ? Did you not mention in the last line of your first paragraph that every element of $S$ is eitehr an opne interval, **a half opten of the form $[a, c)$ or...** ?

Comment: Of the form $[a,c)$, meaning the left endpoint must be $a$.  In your case, $a=-1$, not $.5$.

Comment: Oh OK OK. Now I undesrtand. Thanks.